# LDAP vs Relational Database

Tags: authentication, ldap, authorization, relational-database

I come to you after a desperate disappointing search online for an answer to my question:
Which one is faster: LDAP or Relational Database?

I need to setup a system with both authentication and authorization of users.
I know LDAP has the "structure" for that kind of need, but is it really faster than, say, MySQL?

Comment: The question is unanswerable.  Performance is a characteristic of **implementations**, not of models.  Plus, I have seen LDAP systems that were lightning fast in read mode, but where updating the directory required locking the root of the hierarchy.  Things really stopped being "fast" anytime that happened ...

Comment: Erwin, actually no. The question is certainly answerable - LDAP is a lightweight binary protocol, SQL is a heavyweight ASCII-based language. So by design, LDAP is much less resource intensive and is faster to parse and process. As for implementations, OpenLDAP is orders of magnitude faster than all SQL servers in existence, particularly for authC/authZ tasks but also for anything else that lends itself well to a hierarchical data layout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For authentication and authorization purposes, in my opinion LDAP provides the best mix between performance and simplicity or installation and maintenance. LDAP as a protocol is quite small, requiring relatively little network bandwidth. The small protocol also makes encrypted transmission fairly high-performance.

LDAP is also simple, servers are easy to deploy, and modern, professional-quality LDAP servers provide impressive performance vs. relational database, all other things being equal such as hardware and query type.

I agree that either could be used in your case, but generally LDAP is better for authentication and authorization because of its simplicity and lower maintenance costs. As for performance, the LDAP server with which I am testing provides about 28,000 authentications per second vs. postgres providing about 42% of that number on the same hardware, though it is difficult to compare apples and oranges.

Modern professional-quality LDAP servers also provide extremely powerful and fast cryptographic hashes for secure password storage - as well as reasonably strong reversible block ciphers like AES in the event a reversible password is required if the client must SASL's DIGEST-MD5 mechanism for password-less authentication.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Al, it is impossible to say generally which is faster. It's all contextual.
I love that after this truism, Al then offers up a general opinion that LDAP is slow. :) I digress...

Joking aside, it comes down to what you're trying to do vs. what the target system is optimized to do. MySQL/MSFT SQL Server/etc. are built as general purpose stores where you will (tend) to store normalized data with a variety of query patterns over the data. They have all sorts of logic at many layers of the stack to try and help you do a variety of types of queries & computations over your data, and even let you hint things in to the QP when you know best.
LDAP directories tend to be optimized quite differently...like for the storage of hierarchically organized objects with a specific set of query patterns over it (as specified by LDAP RFCs). AD for example is fast...quite fast. It's optimized for object search & retrieval and associated operations (like auth).

Like anything, you can use either well or poorly.

Short of being in a crazy scale mode, I suspect you could use either quite successfully.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is not a real question, because **it always depends on particular implementations**.

I can put here only my experience: LDAP is slow, SQL is fast. I use MS SQL 2008 and in my case it is very fast thanks to its intelligent caching of repeated queries.

But do you need it to be exceptionally fast? LDAP-based solution can often offer easier and better integration to other software and/or LAN infrastructure when working with users, authorization and authentication.

Comment: What is your particular implementation of LDAP?

Comment: EJP: Active Directory on Windows Server.

Comment: I'd like having laughing reaction here in SO, no other comments.